# how to remove a rel="nofollow" using call to action plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to remove a specific link.`<a href="xyz.com" **rel="nofollow"**>`remove a nofollow link using call to action plugin . may i know how to know the rel="nofollow". i checked in plugin file but. I can't change it. so if you have any suggestion give me fast.

Comment: What plugin? How do you expect people to help if you don't even name the plugin? Regardless, 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: i i think you want to remove from every nofollow link from that page. m i right

Comment: yes  need nofollow link every

Comment: i face this issues when i do seo task. it needed to remove rel="nofollow" attr from all a tags. i hope my code helps you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i hope its help you

i'm doing use of jquery

```
$("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("rel")){
        $(this).removeAttr("rel");
    }
});
```

it will remove all nofollow link from all anchor tag even plugin link too.

Comment: it's working properly.

Comment: I would recommend to replace it with jQuery  instead of $